# Jquery click firing on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use Bootstrap's Collapse feature with custom icons from font-awesome. I am able to get the collapse to work but the problem I am having is that all of the icons are being triggered with Jquery's click, I want to scale this because at any given time the amount of "containers" can change. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $faChevronDown = $('.fa-chevron-down');
    var z = 0;
    $faChevronDown.click(function () {
        if (z == 0) {
            turnUp();
            z++;
        } else {
            turnDown();
            z = 0;
        }
    });
});

function turnUp() {
    $faChevronDown.removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    $faChevronDown.addClass('fa-chevron-up');
};

function turnDown() {
    $faChevronDown.removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $faChevronDown.addClass('fa-chevron-down');
};
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74t2jLcu/4/)

Thank you
Edit : Thank you for the great answers!

Comment: I've simplified it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/74t2jLcu/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point of your `z` variable is, but you can reduce what you have, and fix the problem of not referencing the element by using `this`, by using just:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-chevron-down').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up')
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/74t2jLcu/7/)**

Comment: Thank you, works great! Edit - I was using .toggle until I went through the "why is everything hiding, oh it was deprecated!" loop. I will accept answer in 4 minutes, looks like the most efficient way to do it!!

Comment: Wouldn't this break if the chevron was up for some reason (a trigger from angular etc) on page load? Edit: Yes it does! Edit: Changed to .fa - fixes it. I will probably use an element selector because I am using chevrons in other locations too.

Answer (score 2):

Set click handler on the parent element of a `.fa-chevron-down` element or if the parent element is not known on `body` element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var z = 0;
    $("body").on("click", ".fa-chevron-down", function () {
        if (z == 0) {
            turnUp.call(this);
            z++;
        } else {
            turnDown.call(this);
            z = 0;
        }
    });
});

function turnUp() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-up');
};

function turnDown() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-down');
};
```

If you are using `z` variable only for switching classes `fa-chevron-down` and `fa-chevron-up`, the code could be simplified to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".fa-chevron-down", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, wouldn't this cause a problem when the turnDown function gets called? the click might stop working because .fa-chevron-down is selected and is no long available.

Comment: @Dnwebdev always welcome! Please feel free to accept my answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You are clicking only one element, but your function is changing all icons, you have use $(this) instead in order to only change the icon you are clicking:

```
function toggleClass() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
};
```

and then use only one function:

```
$faChevronDown.click(toggleClass);
```

With this you avoid the use of Ifs and elses and the code is much simplier and small.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the element to perform granular toggling,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $fa= $('.fa');
    var z = 0;
    $fa.click(function () {
        if (z == 0) {
            turnUp($(this));
            z++;
        } else {
            turnDown($(this));
            z = 0;
        }
    });
});

function turnUp(el) {
    el.removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    el.addClass('fa-chevron-up');
};

function turnDown(el) {
    el.removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    el.addClass('fa-chevron-down');
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, this seems to work until you close one and then open another, I believe the selector is lost after that.

Comment: Ah I see, you are removing the fa-chevron-down class which is where the click event is bound. I would recommend binding with a different class from the one you are adding/removing. You can bind to .fa and continue to use the chevron classes elsewhere. I'll update.